# Access Denied exception being thrown in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app

I'm trying to save a video file to a specific folder location instead of a library; which is what it defaults saves to. I'm using StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync to get the location. When it reaches that line in the function it'll throw the exception. 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

```
 private async Task StartRecordingAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                // Create storage file for the capture
                var videoFile = await _captureFolder.CreateFileAsync("SimpleVideo.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
                var encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);

                // Calculate rotation angle, taking mirroring into account if necessary
               

                Debug.WriteLine("Starting recording to " + videoFile.Path);

                await _mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(encodingProfile, videoFile);
                _isRecording = true;
                _isPreviewing = true;

                Debug.WriteLine("Started recording!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // File I/O errors are reported as exceptions
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception when starting video recording: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Code in between

```
   private async Task SetupUiAsync()
        {
            var lvmptVid = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\Users\\Nano\\Documents\\lvmptVid");
           // var videosLibrary = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Videos);
           // var picturesLibrary = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
            // Fall back to the local app storage if the Pictures Library is not available 
            _captureFolder = lvmptVid;
        }
```

I've tried using different saving techniques, currently in the process of revamping the process.
I've tried using a public file location instead of a user specific one.

Comment: The UWP security model requires the user to grant you access to a folder before you can use it. Use the FolderPicker to ask the user to pick a folder. Once picked, you have access to it through the returned folder object. You can use the Future Access List to save that permission for later use

Comment: @RaymondChen I tried that and it worked, thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to use `GetFolderFromPathAsync` to get the file directly using a path, please make sure that you've enabled the **broadFileSystemAccess** capability in the manifest file.

Like this:

```
    <Package
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Please also remember to enable the file system settings in **Settings > Privacy > File system**.

Like this:
[image]

Comment: So what I figured out too was that I didn't have this line in the capabilities section of the manifest:  <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/>

Comment: @MichaelA Glad to hear that. I did not notice that your link contains the `Documents` library which just need the `documentsLibrary` capability. My solution works for the files that are not listed in the libraries like document, video, picture.